# ValueError: Not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1) - tuple DOES contain 3 elements

Tags: python-3.x, properties, tuples

I've created a class property to handle image data and then I'm trying to assign data to this property using a 3-element tuple. For some reason Python seems to think that my tuple contains just one element. Any ideas about what's going on here?

The property setter is defined as follows:

```
@data.setter
def data(self, *args):
    image_array, dtype, sizes = args
    if image_array is None:
        self._data = np.empty(sizes, dtype)
    else:
        self._data = np.array(image_array, dtype)
        self._set_color_data()
```

And upon execution, I get the following output:

```
test = (image_temp, np.uint8, sizes)
print(len(test))
>>> 3
self.image5d.data = test

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\***\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "c:***\mmCIAD\mmciad.py", line 88, in open_file
self.image5d.data = test
File "c:\***\mmCIAD\mmciad.py", line 172, in data
image_array, dtype, sizes = args
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not `def data(self, args)`? I suspect `*args` just packs the tuple in the first item so you get something like `args = [(v1, v2, v3)]`

Comment: @ReutSharabani, wow that was actually the problem! I don't understand why, though, because I've tried `self.image5d.data = image_temp, np.uint8, sizes` as well and that also didn't work. The way I understood it was that the asterisk was required for that type of argument

Comment: @ReutSharabani Do you want to post it as an answer, so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Done. There is only syntactic difference between your attempts, they are interpreted the same way. Try `x = 1, 2, 3` and then `type(x)`, The unpacking syntax depends on the interpreter's opportunity to recognize it. Currently it is still a tuple that is assigned and passed on to the setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
def data(self, args):
```

Currently `*args` just packs the tuple in the first item so you get:

```
args = [(v1, v2, v3)]
```